# What's a good example of a mathematical formula looking more aesthetical in LaTeX than a purely text-based approach?

Tags: mathematics, teaching

I am aware that one can argue about aesthetics, but I am currently introducing some students to LaTeX. I want to present a mathematical formula to show why LaTeX looks more aesthetically pleasing in many cases and thought that there might be some mathematical formula that looks much less aesthetically pleasing when attempting a purely text-based approach. Unfortunately I can't think of any real good examples and the classic examples like 1/2 or a^b could still be talked away in some way. It should be an example that makes very clear that the LaTeX variant looks much more aesthetically pleasing than the purely text-based one.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Showing commutative diagrams to them might be a good idea, since diagrams are hard to produce without LaTeX. Check the documentation of `tikz-cd`, for example.

Comment: Also, with TeX you shall have plenty of choices for math font, which does not come with usual formula editors.

Comment: This showed up in the posted answer, but what do you mean by "purely text-based"?  Do you mean only ascii (in which case, any formula will satisfy your question)?  Or also including unicode (in which case, my guess is any formula where spacing and location are important)?  Or mathml?  Or whatever Office 365 uses?  Or MathJax?

Comment: Integrals and summations look better, even comparing \displaystyle and \textstyle.

Answer (score 3):

Just to name a few.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
% \usepackage{kpfonts}

\begin{document}

$\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}$

$\mathcal{O}_\mathbb{K}$

$\binom{n}{m}$

$A_n^m$

$\overline{x}, \widetilde{x}, \vec{x}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

With custom font:

[image]

*Update by mickep*: To have something to compare with, I entered the same formulas in Office 365, without any other changes (by default a different font, so not fair). This was my first time with a modern office, and it was pretty painless, but a bit slower. I'm sure someone more used to that system could do better. Here is the output.

[image: same formulas with office 365]

That is what we get in the browser. If I save it as a pdf, the formulas get centered on the page (probably my fault, but I have not changed anything, maybe I inserted them as displayed formulas), and the formulas are set in cambria. It looks better:

[image: image from office, exported to pdf]

Comment: I added a comparison with output from office. I hope you do not mind. If you do, please just change it back.

Comment: @mickep Thank you, that is very nice ;)

Comment: Although I realized that the question was for a comparison with a "purely text-based approach", whatever that should mean. In any case, now it is as it is.

Comment: @mickep Yes, but I really cannot think of what "purely text-based approach" can achieve, except like `a_b`, `a^b` or `a/b`. Direct usage of unicode math symbols definitely won't look very good.

Comment: @mickep -- Curious.  Office used `amsfonts`-style blackboard bold, not the style shown in the Unicode charts.  And I would have expected Cambria for the variables.  ???

Comment: @barbarabeeton Updated. When exporting to pdf, I got cambria indeed.